# VS Code extension: how to get word type

Tags: regex, api, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension that will display the visual diagram of a regular expression if the cursor is over a RegExp word (ie: could be a simple string "^regex$" or language-specific way to define a regex like in JavaScript /^regex$/).

So I'd need to know what type of element the cursor is over: is there a way to know that using VSCode API ?

If I could detect that the word is either a String or a RegExp, this would be great. I know that other editors like Atom provide APIs to have access to this but didn't find anything in the VS Code docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question: right now (June 2016), it's not possible yet. This is what the official @code twitter told me.

It's planned but there is no timeline.

See: https://twitter.com/warpdesign_/status/739411149855297536